# Unit testing directives with nested dependencies

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I am an angularJS beginner and I am trying to unit test a directive that has nested dependencies, I have tried different things but the service is always undefined. How do i go about this, I have given the structure of my code below.

```
  apps.directive('directive1', function($compile, service1){
     return {
        restrict : 'EA',
        templateURL: 'directive1.html',
        scope: {

        },
        link: function(scope, element, rootScope){

        },
        controller: function($scope, $element,$rootScope){
        }
    }
 });
```

First service

```
apps.factory('service1', function($q, $http, service2){

}
```

second service

```
apps.factory('service2', function($q, $http, service3){

}
```

third service

```
apps.factory('service3', function($q, $http){

}
```

Comment: What's the problem here? Or is it the same that in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34179876/how-to-mock-service-for-angularjs-directives-controller

Comment: It's the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34179876/how-to-mock-service-for-angularjs-directives-controller is the progress i made after going through some tutorials.

Comment: Ok. Sorry I didn't see it before.