# How to mock service for angularjs directive's controller

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I have a directive that i want to unit test. This works but i need to use the service in the controller. How do i go about this?

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: true,
    templateUrl: 'my-directive.html',
    controllerAs: 'md',
    link:function (scope){

    },
    controller: function($scope, $element, $stateParams,service1) {
          this.test = service1.testData;
    }
  }
});
```

And my unit test file so far

```
describe("Directive : my directive", function() {
 var element, scope, controller, service1,stateParams;

 beforeEach(module("app"));
 beforeEach(module('src/templates/my-directive.html'));
 beforeEach(function() {
    service1 = {
        method : {
            name : "Test"
        }
    };
 });

 beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope ) {
   scope = $rootScope.$new();
   element = "<my-directive></my-directive>";
   element = $compile(element)(scope);
   scope.$digest();

   controller = element.controller("myDirective");

  }));

  it("should do something to the scope", function() {
     // test functions using service1
  })

});
```

and my service

```
app.factory('service1', function(){
      service1.testData = false;

      service1.myPromise = function (t) {
                               var deferred = $q.defer();
                               $http.get("....")
                               .success(function(result) {
                               deferred.resolve(result)
                           })
                           .error(function(error) {
                                deferred.reject(error)
                            });
                           return deferred.promise;
                        } 
});
```

How do i add my mocked service to my controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before compiling the directive you can use the [$provide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide) service in a `beforeEach` block.

```
var service1;
beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
  service1 = {
    testData: 'Test data',
    myPromise: function() {}
  };
  $provide.value('service1', service1);
}));
```

If your service method returns a promise, you can spy on the method and return a promise when the method is called.

```
var deferred;
beforeEach(inject(function($q) {
  deferred = $q.defer(); 
  spyOn(service1, 'myPromise').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);
}));
```

So later in your specs you can reject or resolve the promise.

```
deferred.resolve();
deferred.reject();
```

Comment: What happens if i want to replace the value of testData in the 'it' part to test for a failure. eg it('should fail', function(){ service1.testData = 'value to fail'});

Comment: Does the original `service1` return a promise? Or what's the implementation?

Comment: I've updated my answer. You can also have a look at [my repository](https://github.com/Puigcerber/angular-unit-testing) where I show some unit testing patterns.